# Finding objects in images with inhomogeneous background

Tags: image-processing, segmentation

I have the following `image` where bright circular shaped objects are seen. The `image` has usually an inhomogeneous background and the objects have different sizes and brightness's.

[image]

The aim is to remove the background noise and to **detect all object's positions**.

How can that be done best?

My solution for the example `image` is:

```
fileNameOpen = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
image = Import[fileNameOpen]

background = ImageConvolve[image, GaussianMatrix[7]];
subImage = Image[ImageData[image] - ImageData[background]];

t = FindThreshold[subImage, Method -> "Entropy"];
binImg = Binarize[subImage, t];
binImg = DeleteSmallComponents[binImg, 1];

resultImage = 
 Show[image, 
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, 
    Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
     ComponentMeasurements[
       ImageMultiply[image, binImg], {"Centroid", 
        "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2]]}]]

fileNameSave = SystemDialogInput["FileSave"];
Export[fileNameSave, resultImage];
```

That gives as output:

[image]

The problem is that I have to adjust manually the radius of `GaussianMatrix` and the number in `DeleteSmallComponents`. Their optimum values depend also on the `Method` used in `FindThreshold` (e.g. `"MinimumError"` can also be used") .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> BilateralFilter replaces each pixel by a weighted average of its neighbors, using normalized Gaussian matrices as weights.

so

```
BilateralFilter[i, 4, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is "almost" your background.

If you have troubles with fine-tuning for other images, you may "calculate" the `4` as

```
Round[Sqrt[Total@Flatten@ImageData@SelectComponents[MaxDetect[i], "Area", -1]/Pi] // N]
(* 4 *)
```

Use it like this:

```
pts = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@ImageSubtract[i, BilateralFilter[i, 4, 1]], 
                           "Centroid"];

Show[i, Graphics[{Red, Point[pts[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I like that very much ... you found even all objects at the edges ... solved ... thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the `j` where you calculate the `4`?

Comment: @mrz Sorry, I forgot to paste it. Done.

Comment: @mrz if other images don't perform well please upload a few to analyze them

Comment: Thank you for you help. Here I have a difficult image (with 2 blurred objects due to movement during the image duration) which I cannot solve this way ... may be I am doing something wrong: http://goo.gl/5sg89w

Answer (score 9):

A better way of removing the background might be to use a [`TotalVariationFilter`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TotalVariationFilter.html), which seems to be less sensitive to the parameter it is given compared to convolution. In fact, I've not even used any parameters.

Your code can also be simplified since `Binarize` takes a `Method` option. In fact, you don't actually need it, the automatic method works just as well.

The size option of `DeleteSmallComponents[]` depends on the minimum feature size in your image, so using a value of 1 is a good assumption in this example, but may vary for other images.

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/czhuI.png"];
background = TotalVariationFilter[image];
subImage = ImageSubtract[image, background];

(* Or use Binarize[subImage, Method -> "Entropy"]; *)
binImg = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize@subImage, 1];

resultImage = Show[image, 
                   Graphics[{Red, Disk[#, 2] & /@ 
                   ComponentMeasurements[binImg, "Centroid"][[All, 2]]}]
              ]
```

[image]

Comment: Great ... only at the lower left and right corners you detect objects which are not seen in the image. But when I use **`TotalVariationFilter[image, MaxIterations -> 100];`** your code produces perfect results.